# Konacha - stubing and ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, sinon

konocha 3.2.3, rails 4.0.2. I want to stub didInsetElement method in my Ember View

I use

> sinon.stub(App.ToyBoxView, "didInsertElement")

but I get

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property didInsertElement as function
at Object.wrapMethod (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:522:23)
at Object.stub (http://localhost:3500/assets/sinon.js?body=1:1662:22)
at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3500/assets/aptp/routes/application_route_spec.js?body=1:12:22)
at invoke (http://localhost:3500/assets/ember-mocha-adapter.js?body=1:60:8)
at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3500/assets/ember-mocha-adapter.js?body=1:52:11)
at Hook.Runnable.run (http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:4319:15)
at next (http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:4609:10)
at http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:4626:5
at timeslice (http://localhost:3500/assets/mocha.js:5733:27)
```

my View:

```
App.ToyBoxView = Ember.View.extend Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport,
  properties..
  didInsertElement: ->
    console.log "Something"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `didInsertElement` on `App.ToyBoxView` and it only exists on instances, not on the type definition itself.

Comment: you thinking about:

`
  describe 'App.ApplicationRoute', ->
    beforeEach ->
      App.ToyBoxView.reopen
        didInsertElement: ->
          true
`
this works fine but dont look well

Comment: No, I mean, stub takes an instance as its first parameter.  You are passing in a type.

Comment: I tried 
sinon.stub(App.__container__.lookup('view:toy_box'), 'didInsertElement') but doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately that would be the only instance you could get properly.  Are you trying to prove `didInsertElement` was called in a particular view during transition?

Comment: yes I add alert in didInsertElement and it is called